# Override Control Style

Tags: wpf, styles, themes, overriding

I have created a CustomControlLibrary.dll, that contains a Control (MyControl), with its style in the Generic.xaml of the Themes folder, as per the default automatic setup.

If I want to include that dll in 2 different projects, each of which providing a custom style for "MyControl" to give it a different look, where do I put those custom styles?

I thought I just had to have a Themes\Generic.xaml for each application, that defines the custom style, but having done this, it still ends up using the style defined in CustomControlLibrary.dll

Answer (score 0):

You have CustomControlLibrary.dll which is the owner of MyControl. Inside that dll you have your themes defined. Any other project that may contain your dll doesnt haven to have themes defined.

Other projects may define their custom style for MyControl in their window resource for example.

Styles may be defined at any level. :)

Check this link out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solution will be to define specific style for each project and apply it correspondingly.
But keep in mind that you can create proper style "inheritance" by using [BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) property. After all you should get a set of styles that you'll manage in [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CustomControlLibrary;component/styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```